# Does convergence imply continuity in topology when a topology is first countable?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Simmons 'An Introduction to topology' and came across this question that I haven't been able to solve.

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a mapping of one topological space into another, and if $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$ implies $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ in $Y$ then $f$ is continuous if $X$ is first countable.

Here, $x_n \rightarrow x$ means for the sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ each neighbourhood $G$ of $x$ has a positive integer $n_0$ such that $x_n$ is in $G$ for all $n \geq n_0.$

I am not very familiar with how to prove a function is continuous, all I know is $f$ is continuous if $f^{-1}(G)$ is open when $G$ is open,but I was not able to prove that here.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE ^_^

Hint:

Instead of checking that $f^{-1}(\text{open}) = \text{open}$, you can check that
$f^{-1}(\text{closed}) = \text{closed}$. If this isn't obvious, it's also a nice exercise.

But one of the most important properties about first countable spaces is that $x \in \overline{A}$ if and only if $x$ is the limit of some sequence $a_n \in A$.
(If you're looking for googleable buzzwords, this says that every first countable space is [Frechet-Urysohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space))

So now take a closed set $F \subseteq Y$, and look at $f^{-1}(F)$ in $X$. We want to show that $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed, so let's take some limit point and show that it's already in the set. By the previous paragraph, limit points look like sequences. But we have a hypothesis on how $f$ interacts with sequences... Can you finish it from here?

---

I hope this helps ^_^